# React Hook form with Dynamic key names creates huge array instead

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I am working on creating form inputs, where the IDs of the inputs match an item id from the backend data.  I need to keep track of the dynamic IDs, so I want the name of the fields to match also.

How can I create a form with an object of dynamic field names?  It seems that RHF creates an array instead, so if my itemID is 7841 the array is 7841 in length?

```
interface DynamicCharges {
  ...other fields with static names
  additionalCharges: {
    [id: number]: { // where the `id` comes from the backend so i need the input to follow this
      qty: number;
      amt: string;
    };
  }
}
```

and then implementing the UI:

```
const chargesWithDynamicIds = (additionalCharges || []).reduce(
    (acc, additionalCharge) => {
      const keyName = `_${additionalCharge.id}`;
      return {
        ...acc,
        additionalCharges: {
          ...acc.additionalCharges,
          [keyName]: {
            qty: 0,
            amt: '$0.00',
          },
        },
      };
    },
    otherStaticChargesToInitObj
  );

 const methods = useForm<ReservationChargesShape>({
    defaultValues: chargesWithDynamicIds,
  });


<Controller
  name={`additionalCharges.${additionalCharge?.id}.qty`}
  control={control}
  render={({ value, onChange }) => (
    <Input
      value={value}
      onChange={e => {
        onChange(e.target.value); // sets the actual QTY input
        setValue( // sets the AMT field that is dependent on this QTY change 
          `additionalCharges.${additionalCharge?.id}.amt`,
          formatMoney(
            Number(e.target.value) *
              centsToDollars(
                additionalCharge?.maximum_unit_amount
              )
          )
        );
      }}
    />
  )}
/>
```

the original /default form state looks OK

[image: original form state with obj]

But it turns into an array once the form re-renders

[image: form state after re-render is now an array]

What am I doing wrong with this?

EDIT: I think this is related to the small snippet [in their docs](https://react-hook-form.com/v6/api#register):

> can not start with a number or use number as key name

What I have done is to prefix the field with `_` so the key is no longer numeric, but `_7841`.  Is there any other solution to numeric keys?

Comment: Are you using RHF's `useFieldArray`? Can you share your code, where you initialise `useForm`?

Comment: I am not using Field Array.  Our fields are all known ahead of time and they will not be edited.

Comment: I have added my initialization

Comment: Ok, i saw you already figured it out. Yes, you can't use numbers as keys as RHF will then treat them as array items - that's why i asked if you wanted to use a field array. Also from the docs: `To produce an array of fields, input names should be followed by a dot and number. For example: test.0.data`. So i think your solution using a prefix is the way to go.

Answer (score -3):

The problem come from that you're calling onChange inside your onChange event.
To set the actual QTY input you should use a useState.